# Why are Discrete Fourier Transform "shifted"?

Tags: fourier-transform

I am studying discrete Fourier transform (my question is about 2D DFTs) and comparing my results with some examples I found on the web. At first, I thought my results were wrong as they looked different (with similar inputs, different outputs) until I realized that the outputs of the DFTs I was looking at on the Web had been shifted (quadrants 1 and 3, and 2 and 4 are swapped). That is the standard way by which results of 2D DFTs are displayed/presented (or so it seems).

Why is it so? Is there any practical reason? For example it facilitates processing down the line, like kernel multiplication?

Comment: So instead of displaying from wavenumber $0$ - $2N$, it is also common to display from $-N$ to $N$ which is the same, owing to the periodicity. The only benefit I can think of is that you can easily see symmetry / antimetry in the later style, which indicate if the signal is real - valued or not.

Comment: @Rezha Thank you. Yes, that seems like a good explanation; as is, it's more for convenience and readability than anything else, and your note on periodicity is a good one. Can you elaborate a bit more please, on "the signal is real if there's symmetry". Happy to accept your comment as an answer if you write it as one).

Comment: For real-valued signal, the coefficient of wavenumber $N$ has to be complex conjugate of that for $-N$. So when you plot the real part, it has to be symmetric, while the imaginary part has to be antimetric.

Comment: @Rezha: yes thank you. I also find this post on the topic which is interesting: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2560/discrete-fourier-transform-symmetry

Comment: Also, if you notice, if you use $m$ points as input, you get $m$ points in the DFT output. However, if you know the signal is real valued, you only need to keep $m/2$ points because of the symmetry / antimetry property. This is exactly what most software in industry do.